# Como fazer um layout fatiado utilizando o framework codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou tentando criar um sistema `CRUD` básico utilizando o `codeigniter`, onde o cabeçalho e o rodapé da página fiquem fixos e o conteúdo dinâmico, mas não tenho a menor ideia de como fazer isso. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Fala brother, dê um olhadinha http://flaviosilveira.com/2010/habilitando-layouts-no-codeigniter-template-engine-1/ acredito que vá te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crie uma view como index

**view_index.php**

```
<?php 
$this->load->view('includes/header');//INCLUI A VIEW DENTRO DA PASTA VIEW/INCLUDE/HEADER.PHP
$this->load->view('includes/menu');//INCLUI A VIEW DENTRO DA PASTA VIEW/INCLUDE/MENU.PHP
if($tela != '') $this->load->view('telas/'.$tela);//VERIFICA SE FOI PASSADA A VIEW PELO CONTROLLER SE NÃO ELE USA O CONTROLLER INDEX COMO PADRÃO
$this->load->view('includes/footer');//INCLUI A VIEW DENTRO DA PASTA VIEW/INCLUDE/FOOTER.PHP
```

Depois é só você passar os dados pelo controller que ele puxa a view de acordo com cada função que você criar e passar o nome da view pela variável $dados

**crud.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Crud extends CI_Controller {
    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();//CHAMA O CONSTRUTOR DA CLASSE PAI
    $this->load->helper('url');//CARREGA O HELPER
}

public function index(){
    //$this->load->helper('url'); CARREGA APENAS PARA A FUNÇÃO
    $dados  =   array(
        'titulo'    =>  'Crud com CodeIgniter',
        'tela'      =>  '',
    );
    $this->load->view('crud',$dados);
}

//TELAS
public function create(){
    $dados  =   array(
        'tela'      =>  'nome_da_view'
    );
    $this->load->view('crud',$dados);
}
```